# Configuring Zookeeper from Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja, templating, zookeeper

I'm trying to configure a Zookeeper Cluster with Ansible. As you might know Zookeeper has two important config files.

**zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg**

I create this file on each cluster member using this jinja2 template:

```
{% for host in groups['zookeeper'] %}
server.{{ loop.index }}={{ host }}:2888:3888
{% endfor %}
```

The result will look like this:

```
server.1=processing1.srv.mycompany
server.2=processing2.srv.mycompany
server.3=indexing1.srv.mycompany
server.4=indexing2.srv.mycompany
server.5=quorumandmonitoring.srv.mycompany
```

**data/myid**

Accordind to the [docs](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup) this file needs to contain an unique id for each member of the cluster.
To keep everything in sync I would like to have the value after `server.` in the `myid` of each host. This means:

- `myid=1` on `processing1`
- `myid=2` on `processing2`
- `myid=3` on `indexing1`
- `myid=4` on `indexing2`
- `myid=5` on `quorumandmonitoring`

And this is where my problem starts: how can I do this in a clever way? An ideal solution would be to use something like the `for host in groups` loop. I would rather not add `host_vars` to my inventory.

Answer (score 1):

In lack of a better idea I chose this rather long approach:

**myid.j2**

```
{% for host in groups['zookeeper'] %}
{% if host == inventory_hostname %}
{{ loop.index }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The idea is to iterate over all hosts and check if the current host being processed matches the host in the list of hosts. If it matches I write the iteration counter to the file.

When I ssh into the boxes I can see their myid files were created according to my need:

```
[root@quorumandmonitoring data]# cat myid
5
```